# How is the billing registered of a Azure Cogntive Service - Container?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

Azure Container Services has the option now to run in [containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/cognitive-services-container-support).

To [register the billing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/text-analytics/how-tos/text-analytics-how-to-install-containers#billing) you have to give your API key + Billing URL.

Even though I configured everything correctly and the service works locally, my calls are not registered as quoata's.

PS: Dont try to run the container without an internet connection, it will block the calls then ;)
[image]

Comment: That's weird. Could you send me a mail with the billing endpoint (don't need API key) and when you got this? My email is henrikn AT microsoft.com.
Thanks!
Henrik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Willem,

Here's what I think is going on: The problem is the linux container host picks an IP address range for the container that includes the IP addresses of your local DNS servers. This makes it impossible for the container to resolve names as requests for that range just end up on the local container network and won't go to the DNS servers.

The problem is [described in this entry](https://superuser.com/questions/1336567/installing-docker-ce-in-ubuntu-18-04-breaks-internet-connectivity-of-host) along with several solutions. The best solution seems to be at the very bottom which is also described [in the docker documentation](https://success.docker.com/article/how-do-i-influence-which-network-address-ranges-docker-chooses-during-a-docker-network-create). The short version of this is to update the routing table on the host with the reserved IP range so that docker won’t pick it for the container.

Hope this helps,

Henrik

Comment: We have added this to our [FAQ of issues](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-containers-samples/wiki/Troubleshooting) on container support for Azure Cognitive Services.